# @media print not working properly in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing, media-queries

Have found/read/tried many answers on this so sorry if the solution has already been posted but Chrome is not displaying print styles correctly with many elements missing (but not all).

Here's how things are set up.

**1. SETUP**

- Print styles are set at the end of the main css file using `@media print`
- There is no media attribute on the link which loads the css file
- We’re declaring `!important` on all print styles
- The print styles override the screen styles where needed (i.e. the screen styles are not wrapped in `@media screen`
- Print emulation in Chrome Dev tools displays print styles perfectly
- But some elements disappear when printing (and/or print to PDF)
- Issue occurs if using the print HTML button or ‘Print’ from the file
  menu
- This issue does not occur in Firefox or Safari

---

**2. TROUBLE SHOOTING**

- Print styles were wrapped in `@media only print {}`
- So tried removing ‘only’ like this `@media print {}` but no difference
- If I incorrectly move ‘only’ to be after ‘print’ like this `@media print only {}`
- Then some of the missing print elements display but others disappear
- As noted elsewhere, tried this hack at the start of the print styles but no luck

  `* {
      -webkit-transition: none !important;
      transition: none !important;
  }`

---

Any help or suggestions would be welcome.

Cheers

Ben

Comment: Are you using a framework like Bootstrap? If so, note that most frameworks also have their own base print styles that you may need to comment out or override.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We're not using a framework, I've also just searched the codebase for `@media print` and everything checks out. Also, there are no extra styles showing in dev tools and in fact, everything displays perfectly when dev tools is set to emulate `CSS Media Print`. It seems as if dev tools and the print dialogue disagree somewhere.

Comment: Try narrowing your vertical margins in Chrome, and/or removing `display: inline-block` from the `presenter-notes__main-content` class.

Comment: Thanks for that, yes, it seems to be `inline-block`. With it removed, the page prints in Chrome but the layout is broken. Adding extra width to the `presenter-notes__main-content` also partially fixes the printing but also leaves the layout broken. Will hack out some adjustments styles but at least the page will print. Wonder why dev tools print preview isn't broken but the print dialogue is? Maybe it's something to do with the page size being set to A4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is caused by the CSS declaration `display: inline-block` on your main content container class, `presenter-notes__main-content`.

An inline-block is essentially a block element on the inside and an inline element on the outside. An inline element is unbreakable in print unless it's line wrapped, in which case page breaks can only occur between lines. That prevents individual lines of text from getting split horizontally by page breaks, which would make the printed document very hard to read. An inline-block is never line wrapped (that's because its content wraps instead of the element itself), and thus is always unbreakable.

So, what happens when you have an element that's too large to fit on a single page, but can't be split across multiple pages? Crazy stuff, that's what! Sure, some browsers may degrade gracefully and just clip the overflow, but others may get confused and remove the element altogether. Computers aren't great at dealing with paradoxes.

Comment: Thanks, what's frustrating is that dev tools emulates the `@media print` styles correctly but the print does not. We're also using an `inline-block` grid so we're a bit stuck unless we implement a different grid for print. Hopefully 20 years of hacking CSS layout is at end now that purpose-built layout tools are finally coming down-stream. Cheers

Comment: If you're using inline-block to place elements side-by-side, that should be fine. You just need to avoid using it on any element that is potentially wider or taller than the smallest printable area you intend to support.

Comment: Yes, it's `inline-block` because it's part of the way the grid works. And yes, I guess it's possible it could be taller than A4 as it's the main content area. Maybe I should just hide the sidebar and make the main area `display: block`?

Comment: That should work. It's always a good idea to hide navigation and interface elements in print media. But if you really need a grid-based layout, feel free to use a table. It's still the best grid there is as far as I'm concerned. And in HTML 5, it's perfectly legit to use a table for layout if you add a `role="presentation"` attribute.